# How do I reduce the number of wait seconds grub waits before launching ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decrease GRUB timeout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43020/decrease-grub-timeout)

I have a dual boot configuration with ubuntu 10.10 and windows. What's the best way to configure grub so that the wait time is 2 seconds instead of 10 seconds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found this in a related post: You can install a program called StartUp-Manager.

The package is called `startupmanager`. You can search for this in the Ubuntu Software Centre or Synaptic or run `sudo apt-get install startupmanager` in a terminal.

After it's installed, it is available in the System > Administration menu options.

Answer (score 22):

Run this in your terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

This will open up the grub configuration file. Look a line similar to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` (Here I have set the grub time to 0). Change the number to 2 or whatever time you desire (in seconds).

Save the file and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: What's the trade-off here?  What do I lose by doing this?

Comment: You have less time to choose another OS or startup parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can change it in `/etc/default/grub` and then run `update-grub`.

Answer (score 2):

You can download Startup manager from Software Center to use GUI

Comment: For a newbie this is the easiest way of doing it.