# GRUB2 lost my Windows 7 install

Tags: 10.04, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 about a week ago and have been able to dual boot between it and Windows 7 without any difficulty.  A few days ago I went to boot windows and it wasn't in GRUB's menu.  Per [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9000/how-do-i-reduce-the-number-of-wait-seconds-grub-waits-before-launching-ubuntu-10/9002#9002), I installed startupmanger, but it 
doesn't seem to offer any options for adding a new OS.

How do I restore Windows 7 to my GRUB2 menu?

Edit: Given that I don't have a `/boot/grub/menu.lst` I'm assuming I'm using GRUB2

Comment: You should not just "assume" grub2.

Comment: 10.04 came with GRUB2 by default (for fresh installations) so it's safe to assume that's what he's using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ubuntu's wiki you have to run this command

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Edit : [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows#What%20if%20Grub%202%20does%20not%20list%20Windows) is the page of the wiki i mentioned.

Comment: This ran successfully, but did not find the windows .  It did find the Windows recovery boot sector, but that was already listed. This computer only has one drive, so its odd that its finding some and not others.

Comment: Then the only idea i can get is restoring the windows bootloader manually (you can find the way here http://kb.acronis.com/content/1507) and then manually restoring grub through the same command as above from a live cd (because windows' bootloader will probably become default when you recover it)

It's probably not the best way but it's the only one i can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Run [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) From a Live-CD or USB and post the results.