# Decrease GRUB timeout

Tags: grub2

The GRUB timeout is 8 seconds. Can this be turned down to 2 or 3 seconds? What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

change the GRUB_TIMEOUT value to 2 or 3

save

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't have an effect if you are booting in UEFI as explained in the bug-report [1918736](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1918736)

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if I have a complete answer as I have a few more questions.

**First - Permissions**: you would normally need sudo to edit grub.cfg. If I'm editing from the commandline, I like nano, which is installed by default, so I would use

```
$ sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

If you haven't used nano before, once you're done editing use Ctl-O (the letter) to save and then Ctl-X to exit (the Ctl-O is optional, Ctl-X will prompt if there were changes)

**Second - Grub**: Editing /boot/grub/grub.cfg is probably not the way to go. Grub2 uses the file /etc/default/grub to get all its options and then generates grub.cfg for you. This is important, because grub.cfg gets updated when there's a kernel update or other things that might affect grub. So if you want your changes to stick you need to edit /etc/default/grub.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
$ sudo update-grub2
```

More on grub here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/

**REMEMBER TO MAKE A BACKUP BEFORE YOU CHANGE SYSTEM FILES** :D

**Third - 10s wait**: I'm not actually sure that grub is your villain here, but hopefully the above will help you figure out if it is. Alternatively, can you elaborate a little more. Are you in the grub menu when you "select Ubuntu to boot?" what happens once you've selected it? Or are you referring to the grub picking a default OS - in that case /etc/default/grub will help.

Comment: Editing grub.cfg with Grub2 is a bad idea period. And of coursE Grub is the "villain" responsible for the 10 sec default timeout on multiple-boot systems!!

Answer (score 1):

A GUI method is to install StartUpManager:

`$ sudo apt-get install startupmanager`

You can [set the Grub2 timeout](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StartUpManager#StartUp-Manager) using this utility.

Comment: startupmanager often causes problems with grub2

Comment: and is not available in Ubuntu 12.04's repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You might try installing a GUI interface startup manager called "Grub Customizer".

Doesn't look like it's in the repos though. But you can find it here at Launchpad:
[Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)

Once installed, boot into Ubuntu, start Grub Customizer and configure it for 0 countdown. Then when you boot there should be no wait.

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to change the value of GRUB_TIMEOUT value to 2 or 3 .

1 - go to super mode

> su -

followed by typing your root password

2- now open the GRUB.cfg file either in vi editor or Gedit (Gedit is easy (GUI))

> vi /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

or

> gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg

3 - then find GRUB_TIMEOUT and change it's value 2 or 3

4 - save the changes

5 - if find any difficulty then watch my video on youtube . 
[click here to watch the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_luWeHXr60)

Comment: As we are talking about Ubuntu by default you can't log into your root account – and you shouldn't change that. I would recommend using `sudoedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. If you want to use gedit simply add a line `VISUAL=gedit` to your `~/.bashrc`. Last but not least, mind the notes on `grub2` from above.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout behaviour is different on systems with EFI and BIOS. EFI grub sticks on 30s. There is bug report on it, [1918736](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1918736). Suggested fix is to set GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT in /etc/default/grub to change the delay from 30 seconds.