# How do you reduce the timeout for Grub2 from 10 to 0 seconds?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decrease GRUB timeout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43020/decrease-grub-timeout)

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, with my Mac OS.

When I select Ubuntu to boot, this waits 10 seconds for my input, unfortunately my keyboard does not respond at this stage.

How can I reduce that 10 seconds to zero seconds?

(I tried to edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg, but permission is denied to save changes)