# How to remove Windows from grub menu and boot straight to ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2

I have removed Windows 7 using GParted, and want my computer to boot straight into Ubuntu, but I still get the dual boot screen, how can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: @StephenMyall Here, Ubuntu is already installed, and Windows is already removed. So this is not a duplicate of any question about how to install Ubuntu.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan understood, but its one of 3 options.  Was hoping the asker would come back and state the same as you and add the clarity that overwriting the current installation is not an option.  Askers needs to be more specific as the other 2 options are to resize the partition or reconfigure grub and I am sure there are duplicate answers for these also.

Comment: @StephenMyall Resizing the Ubuntu system's `/` partition will not change what appears on the GRUB menu. `sudo update-grub` (or `sudo os-prober`) is needed either way.

Answer (score 8):

In the Ubuntu system, run this command in the Terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

That will rebuild the list of available operating systems, and Windows will no longer appear on the list.

There still may *be* a list, since you can choose between different kernel versions, or to test your system's RAM.

So if you find you still don't like the menu, you can make it appear for a shorter time.

- [Decrease GRUB timeout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43020/decrease-grub-timeout)

You can even make it appear for no time at all, by setting the timeout to `0`. Then, if you find you do need to access it, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting, and it will appear.

Answer (score 2):

Boot into Ubuntu and then run the following in the terminal, it will update your `grub` and then you should only see Ubuntu

```
 sudo update-grub
```

If this works and you want to hide the `grub screen` and not have to select any kernels at boot run

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

edit the `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false` to read `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`

I would also recommend changing `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` to `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=1` 
as it will make it easier to press `Shift` or `Esc` to show the grub menu if you need to select old kernels(Previous Version of Linux).  **This is completely optional**, I find it a more reliable way to get to grub menu when needed. It will slow down the boot by that 1sec that the grub is waiting for a key press.

**Note**: if you change `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` or `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` you will need to re-run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and run the command -

```
sudo update-grub
```

it will remove windows entry.

if you don't want to see grub menu *(if it is still showing)* open `/etc/default/grub`. to do this run this command -

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` and change as follows-

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

after doing these run this command again -

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Log in as sudo , then go to /boot/grub/grub.cfg file ,note the position of the description of ubuntu os , ( the position of installed OS begin with 0 ) so if you have only ubuntu note the position 0 
Then search the parameter set default and set the value to 0 :

```
set default="0"
```

Like this you configure your system to boot with the OS with the position 0 ( the first one ) 
I hope that helps you.