# Remove Windows entry in GRUB menu

Tags: boot, grub2, grub-efi

I used to have Windows 8.1 - Linux Mint dual boot. I succesfully removed Windows from the system but Grub still shows Windows in boot options:

[grub menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBeLz.png)

I would like to configure the system the way, that on start up I directly load into Linux Mint without seeing Grub screen options at all.

What I tried so far:

1. `sudo update-grub`
2. `sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_TIMEOUT=10/GRUB_TIMEOUT=0/' /etc/default/grub`

   sudo update-grub
3. Deleted Windows entry using  efibootmgr; it was entry Boot0003, it is no more there:

   ```
   BootCurrent: 0002  
   Timeout: 0 seconds  
   BootOrder: 0002,0004,2003,2001,2002  
   Boot0000* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (70-54-D2-8C-E9-B5)   
   Boot0001* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (70-54-D2-8C-E9-B5)   
   Boot0002* ubuntu  
   Boot0004* Ubuntu  
   Boot2001* EFI USB Device  
   Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM  
   Boot2003* EFI Network
   ```
4. 3 followed by deleting directory Microsoft from `/boot/efi/EFI`.
   Currently `/boot/efi/EFI` has three dirs left:
   `Boot`  `toshiba`  `ubuntu`

Is there anything else I could do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open terminal (`Alt+Ctrl+T`) and follow the below procedure :

- Paste the following command in terminal `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`. It will open a file named `/boot/grub/grub.cfg file`.
- Add `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` at the bottom of this file.

  It will prevent Windows being added to your grub menu.
- Now to write the change, run `sudo update-grub`
- You can then run `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to check that your Windows entry has disappeared.
- Restart your device to check the same.

> Note : If above one doesn't go well you can also visit the link [Removing Windows entry from grub.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166776/how-to-remove-windows-from-grub-menu-and-boot-straight-to-ubuntu)
>
> Happy Ubuntu :)

Comment: awesome, this worked, thanx a lot!

Comment: it's my nature to share knowledge as much I can :)