# How to get rid of Windows option on grub and start Ubuntu without choosing OS

Tags: boot, 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I am trying to follow this guide here : [How do I remove Windows from the UEFI boot menu after custom installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042031/how-do-i-remove-windows-from-the-uefi-boot-menu-after-custom-installing-ubuntu)

The thing is when i run "sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI" i only get [ BOOT ubuntu ] but no windows so i assume afterwards when running upgrade-grab that it's on another folder and it reinstates it .
"Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda3@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi"

I also saw this guide : [Remove Windows entry in GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874186/remove-windows-entry-in-grub-menu)
But the issue in this is that the lenovo logo boots twice if that makes any sense.
Once is the normal boot lenovo and then the lenovo ubuntu logo.

So what do i need to do to completely remove windows bootloader.
And when i power on my matchine it boots on ubuntu without the grub screen (to choose Ubuntu) and without seeing the lenovo logo twice .

P.s this is Ubuntu 20.0.4 and on the installation i picked to delete everything on all drives and just install Ubuntu.

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu 20.04, why did you tag the off-topic 14.04?  (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL or *end-of-life*, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is off-topic too being supported elsewhere).  Please clarify

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking about.  On a uEFI device using modern releases, I see the *brand* logo when the box does it's POST (power on self-test routines), then `grub` makes it quick appearance, then the `plymouth` screen (which on modern releases allows the *brand/OEM* to be show, meaning seeing your lenovo logo more than once is expected....   Seeing `grub` is actually useful in my opinion, as should have have problems, it allows you to boot using an older kernel... and with many modern boxes hitting keys to make it appear can be difficult because of their speed..

Comment: You might try grub-customizer. You can remove unwanted entries and set the timeout value to 0 so that grub isn't seen at all, and remove the 'show menu' under visibility.

Comment: Run `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` Change `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false` to `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true` Save the file and exit

Run `sudo update-grub`