# Expand partition of ubuntu on dual boot

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I have a Dell notebook that originally had only Windows 10 (~800 GB partition). Then, I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 (200 GB partition) in dual boot with windows. So far so good.

Now, I'd like to remove completely the Windows and the dual boot and add that space to my current Ubuntu partition.

So, what I need, is a way to remove the windows from the HD and make my hd only Ubuntu WITHOUT messing with the current Ubuntu installation (only increase the HD space), so that I don't have to install/configure all my work tool's again.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Windows from grub menu and boot straight to ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166776/how-to-remove-windows-from-grub-menu-and-boot-straight-to-ubuntu) and [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: May be better to use space for separate /home partition or /mnt/data partition.To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving  But either way, you should have full backups, so you can easily restore system even if hard drive totally fails and you have to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove Windows by deleting it's partitions. BE careful not to delete the EFI partition as this is used by grub.

Assuming that your windows partitions are before your Ubuntu partition. Growing it will require a move also. This may cause boot errors. I recommend making a new partition with the free space and mount it in your /home directory for data storage.