# Uninstall Remove Windows from Grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows

So First off .Thank You everyone for the enormous help that you all have given me. Any problem i had i would always come digging here.
Now i have a common dual boot system. Ubuntu & Windows .
What i want to do is . I want to remove windows properly.(Not just deleting the partition )
I have the grub Boot Loader. I want to do it properly so that windows doesnt show up on Grub.
So i might need to modify something in Grub.

The reason im trying to open a question because i couldn't find one like this.
All i get is how to remove grub or ubuntu.
Not the one i want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Windows from grub menu and boot straight to ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/166776/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete Windows thoroughly then it should also vanish from the Grub menu after `sudo update grub` (or after a kernel update, which uses the same command eventually). In some cases it might leave an entry in the UEFI menu but that shouldn't be hard to delete.

Comment: BEA-utiful. Ha ha

Comment: Well as long as im at it. I should ask this. How do i get the options back . Recovery Modes, Memory Tests , etc

Comment: What do you mean? Recovery mode won't vanish. In case the Grub menu doesn't appear anymore (which is normal for only one OS present) you can summon it with pressing Esc.

Comment: Im Gonna press escape when its booting. Right? Gonna try ithat right now.

Comment: Oh YES. THank You THank You and Thank You