# How to minimize the time of press ESC key for startup menu in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2

I recently updated my device to use SSD and it is booting so fast, but I have this one annoying issue the `press ESC key for startup menu..`, this option is configured by default to 5 sec, and I want to minimize it to at least 2 sec. I used to know how to do this back when I was using Windows, but I didn't know how to do this here in Linux!
I found this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43020/decrease-grub-timeout)  by **@fossfreedom** to configure the grub file and change the GRUB_TIMEOUT value to 2 or 3, but it was already 0 in my system!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by your **bios**. Your boot disc order may not be specified. So, you must **manually select a boot disc** to set the boot order
on your bios settings.

make sure you select your new SSD on the boot option.